# Message system, showing conversation list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've made a small messaging system using PHP and mysql right. I've linked my users as `sender` and `receiver` in the messages table. I can list the conversation between 2 users alright. But I can't work out a way of showing 1 message result from each conversation!

Say I have user 1, 2 and 3. so my messages table can look like this:

```
===================================================================
    ID    ||    sender    ||    receiver    ||    text    ||    date
===================================================================
    1     ||       1      ||        2       ||    Hello!  ||    timestamp stuff
    2     ||       2      ||        1       ||      Hi!   ||
    3     ||       1      ||        3       ||    Boo!    ||
```

So a conversation is linked as

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (sender=1 OR sender=2) AND (receiver=1 OR receiver=2);
```

So that'll get me an entire conversation between 2 users (really simplified).

Back to the question though, How can I get 1 message from each conversation?

I've tried something like this:

```
(SELECT m.text,m.date,sender.username,receiver.username 
FROM messages AS m 
INNER JOIN users AS sender on m.sender=user.ID 
INNER JOIN users AS receiver ON receiver.ID=m.receiver 
WHERE m.sender=1 OR m.receiver=1
ORDER BY messages.date DESC LIMIT 1);
```

But obviously this doesn't do what I want as only returns one row. I think I know what I need to do, I just don't know how to do it? 
I think I need something like this:

```
SELECT sender.username,receiver.username,m.text,m.date FROM messages AS m 
INNER JOIN users AS sender ON sender.ID=m.sender
INNER JOIN users AS receiver ON receiver.ID=m.receiver
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mes.ID 
              FROM messages AS mes
              WHERE mes.sender=1 OR mes.receiver=1 
              ORDER BY mes.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS convo
ON convo.ID=m.ID;
```

Would something like that work?

If you wanted to see my full sql:

```
(SELECT sender.ID AS senderID,sender.username AS senderUsername,sender.firstname AS senderFirstname,sender.lastname AS senderLastname,sender.othername AS senderOthername,sender.url_name AS senderUrl_name,senderI.path as sender_default_image,
                                                        receiver.ID AS receiverID,receiver.username AS receiverUsername,receiver.firstname AS receiverFirstname,receiver.lastname AS receiverLastname,receiver.othername AS reciverOthername,receiver.url_name AS recieverUrl_name,receiverI.path as reciever_default_image,
                                                        messages.message,messages.date,messages.read
                FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'fishy_messages AS messages
                INNER JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'fishy_users AS sender ON sender.ID=messages.sender
                LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'fishy_profile_default_image AS senderDP ON senderDP.userID=sender.ID
                INNER JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'fishy_users AS receiver ON receiver.ID=messages.receiver
                LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'fishy_profile_default_image AS receiverDP ON receiverDP.userID=receiver.ID
                LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'fishy_images AS senderI ON senderI.ID=senderDP.imageID
                LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'fishy_images AS receiverI ON receiverI.ID=receiverDP.imageID
                    WHERE messages.sender=%d OR messages.receiver=%d ORDER BY messages.date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

and yes I'm using wordpress :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return single result give `Limit 1` on outer query, you have given in INNER query.

```
SELECT sender.username,receiver.username,m.text,m.date FROM messages AS m 
INNER JOIN users AS sender ON sender.ID=m.sender
INNER JOIN users AS receiver ON receiver.ID=m.receiver
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mes.ID 
              FROM messages AS mes
              WHERE mes.sender=1 OR mes.receiver=1 
              ORDER BY mes.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS convo
ON convo.ID=m.ID GROUP BY convo.ID ;
```

Comment: I put it in the inner query as I want 1 message from each conversation where there is a conversation. Say from my example I should get 2 results where sender.ID=1 OR receiver.ID=1. So the limit on the outer query would only return one conversation wouldn't it? If I searched for user.ID=2 I should get only 1 result. thank for answering though!

Comment: Nearly! You're probably right. It's just me being a stupid XD thanks for your help. When I figure it out I'll let you know and accept your answer :p

Comment: All the best.. Any way you need to do `group by conersation.ID`

Comment: Yea I saw that :d never used it before lol. I don't have a conversation ID as such. My unique sort of key is sender.ID  and receiver.ID you know? :S probably why I'm getting confused!

Comment: Right! I've got very close! I think this might be the closest I'll get? I'll add an answer, you copy and I'll accept :p

Comment: if you insist ,i wont deny.. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sender.ID AS senderID,sender.username AS senderUsername,sender.firstname AS senderFirstname,sender.lastname AS senderLastname,sender.url_name AS senderUrl_name,receiver.ID AS receiverID,receiver.username AS receiverUsername,receiver.firstname AS receiverFirstname,receiver.lastname AS recieverLastname,receiver.url_name AS recieverUrl_name,messages.message,messages.date,messages.read 
FROM wp_6_fishy_messages AS messages 
INNER JOIN wp_6_fishy_users AS sender ON sender.ID=messages.sender 
INNER JOIN wp_6_fishy_users AS receiver ON receiver.ID=messages.receiver 
WHERE messages.sender=1 OR messages.receiver=1
GROUP BY messages.sender,messages.receiver ORDER BY messages.date DESC
```

Because I didn't have a `conversation ID/key` as my conversations where between sender and receiver. I've grouped my table by both of those! Which gives me the last 2 messages between those users :)